# How to returns the text() of an xml value with a space between the nodes value?

Tags: sql-server-2008, xquery

In SQL Server 2008 R2,

Considering the following xml

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<data><fr>Chambre standard</fr><en>Standard room</en></data>';
```

How can I return the following string:

```
Chambre standard Standard room
```

Currently, I'm only able to return the string concatenated together without any space by using

```
SELECT @xml.query('//*/text()').value('.', 'varchar(max)')
```

Which return

```
Chambre standardStandard room
```

But I need to insert a space in there.

How could I insert a space between the node text?

Comment: Will the <data> element have additional elements besides just <fr> and <en>?

Comment: There can actualy be more than just fr and en (more language), but your solution could work for the time being.

Comment: I've modified the code with what I think is an improved temporary solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.nodes()` to shred your XML.

```
select T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(128)') as Name,
       T.N.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as Value
from @xml.nodes('/data/*') as T(N);
```

Result:

```
Name  Value
fr    Chambre standard
en    Standard room
```

Then you can use `for xml path('')` to bring it back together.

```
select stuff((select ' '+T.N.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
              from @xml.nodes('/data/*') as T(N)
              for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
Chambre standard Standard room
```

Comment: Is there any documentation online that explains "local-name" in greater detail?